# how do you manage a virtually empty asax file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a virtually empty asax file that has just one line of code:

```
<%@ Application Language="C#" CodeBehind="Global.asax.cs" Inherits="Applications.Global" %>
```

Shouldn't there be more accompanying code?

Applications.Global is defined in the code-behing like this:

```
namespace Applications
{
    public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            //Helper.CacheMasterTemplate();

        }
    }
}
```

but the compiler complains that it cannot load type 'Applications.Global' from the first line of the asax file.  How can I change the code to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the problem. Most often, you get that error because the output path has been changed. It should be `bin`. If you target x86, Visual Studio changes it to `bin\x86\Debug`. Change it back. Go to PROJECT > YourProject Properties > Build and check the Output Path.